# How to use Physics.Checkbox to prevent overlapping when instantiating new gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to spawn my environment object dynamically through code. I made a list of my environment object and spawn it through code (code given) which is working fine but the problem is objects are overlapping with even i used [**Physcis.CheckBox**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckBox.html) to check that if the position is already occupied then change the newly spawn object position.

```
public void HomeObjectPlacer() {

    for (int i = 0; i < ObjectsEnv.Count; i++)
    {
        //Physics.CheckBox(ObjectsEnv[i].transform.localScale,);
        for (int j = 0; j < envPerCount; j++)
        {

            Vector3 newPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(xPosStart, zPosLimit), 0, Random.Range(zPosStart, zPosLimit));
            GameObject instance = Instantiate(ObjectsEnv[i], newPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
            do
            {
            if (!Physics.CheckBox(instance.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<BoxCollider>().center,
                    instance.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<BoxCollider>().size))
                {
                    Debug.Log("instantiated : "+ i);
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    Debug.Log("not instantiated."+ i);

                    newPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range(xPosStart, zPosLimit), 0, Random.Range(zPosStart, zPosLimit));
                    instance.transform.position = newPosition;
                }
            } while (true);

        }
    }
}
```

I guess i am not using Physics.checkbox correctly.

Comment: so you never get the statement "not instantiated." in the `Console` ?

Comment: I have the same issue. How did you fixed this error?